# I need some guidance with replacing all the vectors in my code with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, replace, encode

I wrote a program to encode a normal text file, wihch compresses the text. I had spent all day today working on it, without realizing that I cant use vectors in my code, and instead I should be using arrays. For reasons unknown, I am not good with using arrays. I have a section of my code to share, and I was hoping someone could walk me through the steps of converting my vectors into arrays. I am not posting the full code since it is for a class, but I can add more if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
vector<string> originalText;

// This function is designed to grab the last character of each sorted line, and then add it to a new string

string cluster(vector<string> &sortedLines, string og)
{
    string endColumn = " ";
    string clusterize;
    int count = 0;
    int ogIndex = 0;
    
    if(sortedLines.at(count) != " ")
    {
        // This will check and see if there are clustered characters in the endColumn String.
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedLines.size(); i++)
        {
            endColumn.push_back(sortedLines.at(i).back());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < endColumn.length(); i++)
        {
            int clusterCount = 1;
        
            for (int j = i + 1; j < endColumn.length(); j++)
            {
                if(endColumn.at(i) == endColumn.at(j))      
                {
                    clusterCount++;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            clusterize += to_string(clusterCount) + " " + endColumn.at(i) + " ";
        }
    }
    // This will get rid of the last space of the encoded string.
    clusterize = clusterize.substr(0, clusterize.length() - 1);
    
    // This is to see which index the original string is in our sorted vector.
    for (int p = 0; p < sortedLines.size(); p++)
    {
        if (sortedLines.at(p) == og)
        {
            ogIndex = p;
            break;
        }
        
        else
        {
            clusterize = to_string(ogIndex) + "\n\n";
        }
        clusterize = to_string(ogIndex) + "\n" + clusterize + "\n";
        count++;
            
    }
       return clusterize;
}
```

Comment: Why should you be using arrays rather than vectors?    Also, if you aren't allowed to use `std::vector`, you will probably not be allowed to use `std::string` either.

Comment: *Why* can't you use vectors in your program? Is this a school assignment where the teacher forbids it?

Comment: Which kind of array are you thinking of? The C kind or the C++ kind, close relative of vector?

Comment: Your teacher should be giving you credit for using your initiative. The quality of CS education often disappoints me.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use vectors, why don't you make a (minimal) custom implementation of them and replace all occurrences? That seems less work that replacing everything with arrays. I would name the custom class stdvector just to troll your teacher (assuming this is homework)

Comment: Your teacher should not be teaching you arrays in the first place.  Arrays are an advanced topic.  They are needed to implement vectors and that is all you should know about them.

Comment: the only reasonable thing to do when you are not allowed to use `std::vector` is to reimplement a poor mans version of `std::vector`. Manual managment of a dynamic array is not something that should be sprinkled all around your code

Comment: yes it is a school assignment where vectors are forbidden.

Comment: and I the array I am thinking of is the C++ kind.